# How to avoid nuget conflict reference?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a project A that references NuGet Newtonsoft Json version 11 and I have another project B that references NuGet Newtonsoft Json 13 and also project B. Since project B references a lesser version the NuGet addition throws an error in the Visual Studio. Is there any way to address this or the only way is to have Project A update the Newtonsoft nuget to 13?

Comment: Have a look at [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution)

Comment: I suggest to update. This will most likely cause the least problems. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71867776/different-versions-of-same-dll-in-multiple-nuget-package-in-same-net-6-project/71868096#71868096

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect assembly in related project configuration file. Example:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Read more about Redirecting Assembly here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions